# I am not able to show an error message when the input field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show an error message whenever the form input field `name` is empty but seems it returns nothing; what's wrong with my code?

I am working on the codepen.io server.
I have included jquery 3.4.1 instead of jquery 3.3.1 but seems not working as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstName = document.forms["myForm"]["name"];

  var mail = document.forms["myForm"]["email"];
  var errorMessage = document.forms["myForm"]["error"];

  function check(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (firstName.value == '' || !firstName.value.length) {
      console.log("here");
      errorMessage.innerText = "This is invalid name";
    } else {
      errorMessage.innerText = '';
    }
  }
  firstName.addEventListener('submit', check);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>FCC:Survey Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="survey form helps user fill in  a questionnaire" />
  <meta name="author" content="lily bani, david jhonson" />
  <meta name="description" content="survey, form, questionnaire" />
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=en-US" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- add bootstrap to the website -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- add fonts to make it stylish -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="javascript" src="plain.js" />

</head>

<body class="bigBox">
  <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="description">Let us know how to improve FreeCodeCamp</p>
    <form id="survey-form" action="" method="post" name="myForm">
      <label for="name" id="name-label">
*Name:  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
      <span id="error" name="error"> </span><br/>
    </label>
      <label for="email" id="email-label">
 *Email:  <input type="email" id="email"  name="email" placeholder="Enter your email"/><span id="error" name="error"> </span><br/>
    </label>
      <label for="age" id="number-label">
  *Age: <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="18" max="35" placeholder="Age" />
    </label>
      <p id="one">Which option best describes your current role?</p>
      <select id="dropdown1">
        <option value="select an option" disabled>select an option</option>
        <option value="student">student</option>
        <option value="full time job">full time job</option>
        <option value="full time learner">full time learner</option>
        <option value="prefer not to say">prefer not to say</option>
        <option value="others">others</option>
      </select>
      <div class="two">
        <p>* How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Definitely">Definitely<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="maybe">Maybe<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="notsure">Not Sure
      </div>
      <p id="three">What do you like most in FCC:</p>
      <select id="dropdown2">
        <option value="select an option" disabled>select an option</option>
        <option value="challenegs">challenges</option>
        <option value="projects">projects</option>
        <option value="community">community</option>
        <option value="opensource">open source</option>
      </select>

      <p id="four">Things that should be improved in the future (Check all that apply):</p>
      <fieldset>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Front-end Projects"><label for="go">Front end Projects</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Back-end Projects"><label for="go1">Back-end Projects</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Data Visualization"><label for="go2">Data Visualization</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Challenges"><label for="go3">Challenges</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Open Source Community"><label for="go4">Open Source Community</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Gitter help rooms"><label for="go6">Gitter help rooms</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="videos"><label for="go7">videos</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="city meetups"><label for="go8">city meetups</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="wiki"><label for="go9">wiki</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="forum"><label for="go10">forum</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="additional courses"><label for="go11">additional courses</label><br>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <p id="text_me">Any comments or Suggestions:</p>
      <textarea id="textarea_now" rows="3" cols="25" placeholder="enter your comment here">
</textarea>

      <input type="submit" id="button_me" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- optional javascript... using jquery and popper.js for interactive mode -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link type="text/css" src="plain.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It should return the error `"This is invalid name"` but it's returning nothing.

Comment: Consider share your codepen url directly?

Comment: First problem is that you have multiple elements with the same id `error`

Comment: Only had a quick look, but the action on your form is blank. What javascript event is supposed to fire when you click submit? Update the check function so that it is listening for the click/submit event.

Comment: "I have included jquery 3.4.1"...since none of your code uses jQuery it's not clear how you thought that would affect anything

Comment: I dont know what's going on here...everytime I try ask a question telling me to comeback and ask after 7 days what I have done wrong?????

Comment: Did you try reading the help page relating to your situation? It explains why you may have had limits put on your account. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited

Answer (score 1):

1. replace the line to `<script src="plain.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` to reference a external js file
2. You should reference dependency i.e. jQuery before your own code. The jQuery reference is at the very end of the html but `plain.js` need `$` at the first line. You will hit `$ is not defined` error
3. `firstName` is a textfield and it has no submit event, are you trying to assign the event to the form?
4. `id` should be unqiue across the whole html. There are multiple id with `error` in yours

```js
/**
 * 
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
 var firstName = document.forms["myForm"]["name"];

 var mail = document.forms["myForm"]["email"];

 function check(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var errorMessage = $(firstName).next('.error');
  if (firstName.value == '' || !firstName.value.length) {
   console.log("here");
   errorMessage.html("This is invalid name");

  } else {
   errorMessage.html("");
  }
 }

 $('#survey-form').on('submit', check);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>FCC:Survey Form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description"
 content="survey form helps user fill in  a questionnaire" />
<meta name="author" content="lily bani, david jhonson" />
<meta name="description" content="survey, form, questionnaire" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=en-US" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- add bootstrap to the website -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- add fonts to make it stylish -->
<link
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap"
 rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body class="bigBox">
 <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
 <div class="container">
  <p id="description">Let us know how to improve FreeCodeCamp</p>
  <form id="survey-form" action="" method="post" name="myForm">
   <label for="name" id="name-label"> *Name: <input type="text"
    name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" /> <span
    class="error" name="error"> </span><br />
   </label> <label for="email" id="email-label"> *Email: <input
    type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" /><span
    class="error" name="error"> </span><br />
   </label> <label for="age" id="number-label"> *Age: <input
    type="number" name="number" id="number" min="18" max="35"
    placeholder="Age" />
   </label>
   <p id="one">Which option best describes your current role?</p>
   <select id="dropdown1">
    <option value="select an option" disabled>select an option</option>
    <option value="student">student</option>
    <option value="full time job">full time job</option>
    <option value="full time learner">full time learner</option>
    <option value="prefer not to say">prefer not to say</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
   </select>
   <div class="two">
    <p>* How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a
     friend?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Definitely">Definitely<br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="maybe">Maybe<br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="notsure">Not Sure
   </div>
   <p id="three">What do you like most in FCC:</p>
   <select id="dropdown2">
    <option value="select an option" disabled>select an option</option>
    <option value="challenegs">challenges</option>
    <option value="projects">projects</option>
    <option value="community">community</option>
    <option value="opensource">open source</option>
   </select>

   <p id="four">Things that should be improved in the future (Check
    all that apply):</p>
   <fieldset>
    <div>
     <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Front-end Projects"><label
      for="go">Front end Projects</label><br> <input
      type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Back-end Projects"><label
      for="go1">Back-end Projects</label><br> <input
      type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Data Visualization"><label
      for="go2">Data Visualization</label><br> <input
      type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Challenges"><label
      for="go3">Challenges</label><br> <input type="checkbox"
      name="sources" value="Open Source Community"><label
      for="go4">Open Source Community</label><br> <input
      type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Gitter help rooms"><label
      for="go6">Gitter help rooms</label><br> <input
      type="checkbox" name="sources" value="videos"><label
      for="go7">videos</label><br> <input type="checkbox"
      name="sources" value="city meetups"><label for="go8">city
      meetups</label><br> <input type="checkbox" name="sources"
      value="wiki"><label for="go9">wiki</label><br> <input
      type="checkbox" name="sources" value="forum"><label
      for="go10">forum</label><br> <input type="checkbox"
      name="sources" value="additional courses"><label
      for="go11">additional courses</label><br>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
   <p id="text_me">Any comments or Suggestions:</p>
   <textarea id="textarea_now" rows="3" cols="25"
    placeholder="enter your comment here">
</textarea>

   <input type="submit" id="button_me" class="btn btn-info"
    value="Submit">
  </form>
 </div>
 <!-- optional javascript... using jquery and popper.js for interactive mode -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link type="text/css" src="plain.css" />

 <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="plain.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot what  I have referenced to another external file while javascript file running on the same server and also was using firstName as a submit event while I should use form

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view you definitely have to do few adjustments

1. Change all error spans. `class='error'` instead of `id='error'`.
   According to this [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute).
2. You have to change submit button from `type='submit'` to `type='button'`. This change will help you validate the entire form and to gain more control against your application flow.

And finally here you can find brand new validation function for your form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 const $surveyForm = $('#survey-form');
  $('#button_me').on('click', function(){
  const $name = $('#name');
  const $error = $name.next();
  const isNameValid = $name.val().length > 0;
  $error.text(isNameValid ? '' : 'This is invalid name');
  
    if(isNameValid) {
     $surveyForm.submit();
    }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="description">Let us know how to improve FreeCodeCamp</p>
    <form id="survey-form" action="" method="post" name="myForm">
      <label for="name" id="name-label">
*Name:  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
      <span class="error" name="error"> </span><br/>
    </label>
      <label for="email" id="email-label">
 *Email:  <input type="email" id="email"  name="email" placeholder="Enter your email"/><span class="error" name="error"> </span><br/>
    </label>
      <label for="age" id="number-label">
  *Age: <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="18" max="35" placeholder="Age" />
    </label>
      <p id="one">Which option best describes your current role?</p>
      <select id="dropdown1">
        <option value="select an option" disabled>select an option</option>
        <option value="student">student</option>
        <option value="full time job">full time job</option>
        <option value="full time learner">full time learner</option>
        <option value="prefer not to say">prefer not to say</option>
        <option value="others">others</option>
      </select>
      <div class="two">
        <p>* How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Definitely">Definitely<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="maybe">Maybe<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="notsure">Not Sure
      </div>
      <p id="three">What do you like most in FCC:</p>
      <select id="dropdown2">
        <option value="select an option" disabled>select an option</option>
        <option value="challenegs">challenges</option>
        <option value="projects">projects</option>
        <option value="community">community</option>
        <option value="opensource">open source</option>
      </select>

      <p id="four">Things that should be improved in the future (Check all that apply):</p>
      <fieldset>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Front-end Projects"><label for="go">Front end Projects</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Back-end Projects"><label for="go1">Back-end Projects</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Data Visualization"><label for="go2">Data Visualization</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Challenges"><label for="go3">Challenges</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Open Source Community"><label for="go4">Open Source Community</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Gitter help rooms"><label for="go6">Gitter help rooms</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="videos"><label for="go7">videos</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="city meetups"><label for="go8">city meetups</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="wiki"><label for="go9">wiki</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="forum"><label for="go10">forum</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="additional courses"><label for="go11">additional courses</label><br>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <p id="text_me">Any comments or Suggestions:</p>
      <textarea id="textarea_now" rows="3" cols="25" placeholder="enter your comment here">
</textarea>

      <input type="button" id="button_me" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change submit button type to "button" as you still use `event.preventDefault()`.

Then. You can use html5 validation to check fields value. You need to add `require` attribute to the fileds you want to check. If you want to validate fields and show error message,  you can use `form.reportValidity()` method, whereas `form.checkValidity()` just return boolean value.

```js
// you have to be consistent in code style.
// use native methods for load event as you use native methods to get form element


// You can set custom validation messages or you can use html5 attributes to set rules

let validationMessages = {
  'name': {
    'invalid': 'Please provide a valid name'
  },
  'email': {
    'invalid': 'Please provide a valid email'
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let form = document.forms["myForm"]
  let sbmButton = document.querySelector('#submit-form-button')
  let requiredFields = [...form.querySelectorAll('[required]')]

  // you can put event listener here because functions declared as below bubble up to top of the script during interpretation 
  // to use custom error messages change "check" to "checkCustom"
  sbmButton.addEventListener('click', checkCustom);

  // clear error message on typing
  requiredFields.forEach(field => {
    field.addEventListener('input', () => {
      let errorField = document.querySelector(`#${field.name}-error`)
      errorField.textContent = ''
      errorField.classList.add('hidden')
    })
  })

  // here is the way with using "require" attribute and html5 validation
  function check(event) {
    if (!form.reportValidity()) {
      return false
    }
    // do something if form is valid
  }

  function checkCustom(event) {

    requiredFields.forEach(field => {
      let errorFiled = form.querySelector(`#${field.name}-error`)
      let errorText = ''
      if (!field.value.length) {
        errorText = getEmptyFieldMessage(field.name)
      }
      // check if email or name contains not allowed characters
      else if (!field.checkValidity()) {
        errorText = validationMessages[field.name]['invalid']
      }
      errorFiled.classList.remove('hidden')
      errorFiled.textContent = errorText
    })
  }

  function getEmptyFieldMessage(fieldName) {
    return `The field "${fieldName}" can not be empty.`
  }

});
```

```css
.error-message {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>FCC:Survey Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="survey form helps user fill in  a questionnaire" />
  <meta name="author" content="lily bani, david jhonson" />
  <meta name="description" content="survey, form, questionnaire" />
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=en-US" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- add bootstrap to the website -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- add fonts to make it stylish -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="javascript" src="plain.js" />

</head>

<body class="bigBox">
  <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="description">Let us know how to improve FreeCodeCamp</p>
    <form id="survey-form" action="" method="post" name="myForm">
      <label for="name" id="name-label">
*Name:  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
      <span id="name-error" class="error-message hidden" name="error"> </span><br/>
    </label>
      <label for="email" id="email-label">
 *Email:  <input type="email" id="email"  name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required/><span id="email-error" class="error-message hidden" name="error"> </span><br/>
    </label>
      <label for="age" id="number-label">
  *Age: <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="18" max="35" placeholder="Age" />
    </label>
      <p id="one">Which option best describes your current role?</p>
      <select id="dropdown1">
        <option value="select an option" disabled>select an option</option>
        <option value="student">student</option>
        <option value="full time job">full time job</option>
        <option value="full time learner">full time learner</option>
        <option value="prefer not to say">prefer not to say</option>
        <option value="others">others</option>
      </select>
      <div class="two">
        <p>* How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Definitely">Definitely<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="maybe">Maybe<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="notsure">Not Sure
      </div>
      <p id="three">What do you like most in FCC:</p>
      <select id="dropdown2">
        <option value="select an option" disabled>select an option</option>
        <option value="challenegs">challenges</option>
        <option value="projects">projects</option>
        <option value="community">community</option>
        <option value="opensource">open source</option>
      </select>

      <p id="four">Things that should be improved in the future (Check all that apply):</p>
      <fieldset>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Front-end Projects"><label for="go">Front end Projects</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Back-end Projects"><label for="go1">Back-end Projects</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Data Visualization"><label for="go2">Data Visualization</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Challenges"><label for="go3">Challenges</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Open Source Community"><label for="go4">Open Source Community</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="Gitter help rooms"><label for="go6">Gitter help rooms</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="videos"><label for="go7">videos</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="city meetups"><label for="go8">city meetups</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="wiki"><label for="go9">wiki</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="forum"><label for="go10">forum</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sources" value="additional courses"><label for="go11">additional courses</label><br>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <p id="text_me">Any comments or Suggestions:</p>
      <textarea id="textarea_now" rows="3" cols="25" placeholder="enter your comment here">
</textarea>

      <button type="button" id="submit-form-button" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- optional javascript... using jquery and popper.js for interactive mode -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link type="text/css" src="plain.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```